# Sending arrays using ObjectOutputStream in multi-threaded server

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client/server program with more than two buttons. When a button is clicked it sends a certain request to the server. According to the request the server has to send a string array back. Im using `ObjectOutputStream` on the server side and `ObjectInputStream` on the client side. The problem is that the `ObjectInputStream`does not allow me to call the `readObject()` method more than once. Is there maybe a better way to send arrays across socket connections. I use `PrintWriter` to send the request to the server. My server is multi-threaded.

Client:

```
public FuncListener2()
    {

        butCheckOutSearchTitle.setEnabled(false);
        String hostName = "";

        try {
            hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString(); // to get the hostName for the exceptions
            clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 1211);
            System.out.println(clientSocket.isConnected());
            printWriter = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());


            listeners();

            clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host "+hostName);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "+hostName);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void listeners()
    {
        System.out.println("in listener");

        butCheckOutSearchSurname.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {

                    System.out.println("surname search");
                    int count = 0;

                    String [] array = null;

                    // the reason for the plus sign is to make sure the correct if statement is executed in the server
                    String query = "Select+ * FROM clientDet WHERE clientSurname = \'" + textCheckOutSearchSurname.getText() + "\'";
                    printWriter.println(query);

                    obj = objIn.readObject();

                    if(obj != null)
                    {
                        array = (String[])obj;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("object empty");
                    }

                    listCheckOutClients.setListData(array);


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        listCheckOutClients.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() 
        {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    butCheckOutSearchTitle.setEnabled(true);


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        butCheckOutSearchTitle.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {

                    listCheckOutAvaliable.removeAll();
                    String [] stringArray = null;

                    // the reason for the plus sign is to make sure the correct if statement is executed in the server
                    String query = "Select- * FROM stock WHERE stockTitle = \'" + textCheckOutSearchTitle.getText() + ",\' AND  (stockStatus = \'available\' OR \'reserved\')";
                    printWriter.println(query);

                    obj = objIn.readObject();

                    stringArray = (String[])obj;

                    listCheckOutAvaliable.setListData(stringArray);

                    objIn = null;


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
      }
```

Server:

```
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/videostore", "root", "IronFire");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Server");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            objOut= new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            while (running)
            {
                //SELECT+ searching surname
                //SELECT- searching titles
                //SELECT@ searching ####Num column



                String command = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Query:  " + command);
                if(command.substring(0, command.indexOf(" ")).equalsIgnoreCase("SELECT+"))
                {
                    System.out.println("IN IF +"); // for test
                    surname(command);
                }
                if(command.substring(0, command.indexOf(" ")).equalsIgnoreCase("SELECT-"))
                {
                    System.out.println("IN IF -"); // for test
                    title(command);
                }
                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                {
                    running = false;
                    System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : " + clientID);
                }
                else 
                {
                    out.println(command);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void surname(String query)

    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("In Surname"); // for test
            int count = 0; 
            int whileCounter = 0;
            Statement state = conn.createStatement();

            res = state.executeQuery(query.replace("+", ""));

            while(res.next())
            {
                count++;
            }
            String [] stringResult = new String[count];
            res.beforeFirst();

            while(res.next())
            {
                stringResult[whileCounter] = res.getString(1) +"  "+  res.getString(2) +"  " + res.getString(3)  +"  "+ res.getString(5)  +"  "+ res.getString(10) +"  "+ res.getString(11) +"";
                whileCounter++;
            }


            objOut.reset();
            objOut.writeUnshared(stringResult);
            objOut.flush();



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void title(String query)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = 0; 
            int whileCounter = 0;

            Statement state = conn.createStatement();

            res = state.executeQuery(query.replace("-", ""));
            System.out.println(query.replace("-", ""));

            while(res.next())
            {
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            String [] stringResult = new String[count];

            res.beforeFirst();

            while(res.next())
            {
                stringResult[whileCounter] = res.getString(1) +"  "+  res.getString(2) +"  " + res.getString(3)  +"  "+ res.getString(5) +"";
                whileCounter++;
            }

            for(int a = 0; a< stringResult.length; a++)
            {
                System.out.println(stringResult[a]);
            }

            objOut.reset();
            objOut.writeUnshared(stringResult);
            objOut.flush();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The errors this is the only error and it is on the client side:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 53
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1374)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at FuncListener2$3.actionPerformed(FuncListener2.java:197)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the readObject() as may times as you want.  The problem may be that it block when there is nothing to read.  You can make this reader use a background thread so it doesn't matter that its blocking.

The ObjectOutputStream assumes object are immutable.  If you change an object, it doesn't send it again, instead it send a reference to that object instead.

If you want a new copy of an object to be sent each time you can use writeUnshared() or use reset() between calls.

---

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("hello");

oos.writeUnshared(strings);

strings.set(0, "world");

oos.writeUnshared(strings);

oos.close();

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

System.out.println(ois.readObject());
System.out.println(ois.readObject());
```

prints

```
[hello]
[world]
```

Comment: the way my program works is that i must press one button get the array chose from the array using JList. that will then enable the other button. when i press the button the request sends. but it seems to me that the array that the server send back to the client clashes with the first array.

Comment: I assume you are changing an array you have already sent and sending it again, but you see the original both times? See my edit.

Comment: I try using writeUnshared() but it gives me a StreamCorruptedException.

Comment: It sounds like you are not reading and writing the data as one stream.

Comment: I suspect you are getting an error on the sender side, but you are discarding them so all you see is a corrupt stream on the reader. Can you printout exception on the sender side?

Comment: That is on the receiver side is it not?

Comment: Yes that is on the reciever side

Comment: So can you make sure you are printing out, rather than ignoring, any exception on the sender side?

Comment: I use printStackTrace() in all my catch blocks. It does not display any errors on the sender side.

Comment: I just that you don't in your code in the question.  Can you update your code to reflect this?

Comment: Sorry about that did not notice. I fixed it above as well as in my original code. I run the program again and there is no exceptions on the sender side only on the reciever side.

Comment: I can't see what is wrong from the code, the only thing I can suggest it to log everything. Log everything you send and receive and make sure objOut is not being used anywhere but the code you have listed.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
>
> objOut= new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
> ```

You are registering multiple output streams on the socket, some streams may use buffering, others may get as much bytes there are, or send bytes without you knowing, causing the receiving side receive the bytes out of the correct order, to be sure you don't get these bugs, always register only 1 output stream on the socket, not more.